# Why last element height changed effect the page scrollTop

Tags: html, css

I got a html template like the following:

```
<div> some fixed height pics </div>
<div> some fixed height pics </div>

<div class='tabs'>
    <div class='tab'> tab 1 content height:300px </div>
    <div class='tab'> tab 2 content height:500px </div>
</div>

<div class='tab-content'> tab content </div>
```

When I scroll to the bottom of the page and click the tab, the tab's position will change.
But the position of the tabs will not change if I move the tabs up between the images like this:

```
<div> some fixed height pics </div>

<div class='tabs'>
    <div class='tab'> tab 1 content height:300px </div>
    <div class='tab'> tab 2 content height:500px </div>
</div>

<div class='tab-content'> tab content </div>

<div> some fixed height pics </div>
```

I tried to call a function to scroll the page, but it is not the best way and the UE is not good. Why does the flexible height element at the bottom of the page affect the scrollTop?

I tried to set 'tab-content' 500px height, it is work on android but not work on iOS.

When the height of the 'tab-content' is fixed, I switch tabs without changing the page position. But on iOS there will still be tabs position changes. It looks like page falling down